# PCL - GreedyProjectionTriangulation makes not enough faces

Tags: computer-vision, point-cloud-library, triangulation

I am trying to triangulate my point cloud in Point Cloud Library using **pcl::GreedyProjectionTriangulation** from this [tutorial](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/greedy_projection.php#greedy-triangulation)

**Problem**:
But as the result I got **PolyMesh** with a very few number of faces (see the image below):
[Sorry, I can't publish images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1BMNR.jpg)

Here is my code:

```
//Calculate normals
pcl::NormalEstimation<pcl::PointXYZ, pcl::Normal> n;
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::Normal>::Ptr normals(new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::Normal>);
pcl::search::KdTree<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr tree(new pcl::search::KdTree<pcl::PointXYZ>);
tree->setInputCloud(cloud);
n.setInputCloud(cloud);
n.setSearchMethod(tree);
n.setKSearch(80);

cout << "Computing normals...\n";
n.compute(*normals);

// Concatenate the XYZ and normal fields*
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointNormal>::Ptr cloud_with_normals(new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointNormal>);
pcl::concatenateFields(*cloud, *normals, *cloud_with_normals);

// Create search tree*
pcl::search::KdTree<pcl::PointNormal>::Ptr tree2(new pcl::search::KdTree<pcl::PointNormal>);
tree2->setInputCloud(cloud_with_normals);

// Initialize objects
pcl::GreedyProjectionTriangulation<pcl::PointNormal> gp3;
pcl::PolygonMesh triangles;

// Set the maximum distance between connected points (maximum edge length)
gp3.setSearchRadius(0.1);

// Set typical values for the parameters
gp3.setMu(2.5);
gp3.setMaximumNearestNeighbors(150);
gp3.setMaximumSurfaceAngle(M_PI ); // 180 degrees
gp3.setMinimumAngle(M_PI / 18);    // 10 degrees
gp3.setMaximumAngle(2 * M_PI / 3); // 120 degrees
gp3.setNormalConsistency(false);

// Get result
gp3.setInputCloud(cloud_with_normals);
gp3.setSearchMethod(tree2);
cout << "reconstruct\n";
gp3.reconstruct(triangles);
```

- I tried to set bigger value (1 vs 0.1) of the *SearchRadius*  but got this warning during runtime:

  *Not enough neighbors are considered: ffn or sfn out of range! Consider increasin
  g nnn_... Setting R=23433 to be BOUNDARY!
  Not enough neighbors are considered: source of R=23480 is out of range! Consider
  increasing nnn_...
  Number of neighborhood size increase requests for fringe neighbors: 24
  Number of neighborhood size increase requests for source: 68*

  and number of polygons is steel low.

**Question**: So, what should I do to create good PolyMesh from the point cloud?

Answer (score 2):

Here are some tips that could fix your problem:

- Before calculating normals, try applying a method for a better surface approximation: `MovingLeastSquares` or `BilateralUpsampling` depending on your needs. Your cloud will be more dense, resulting in less holes after surface reconstruction.
- Use radius search instead of K-search for normal estimation, it provides better results to me.
- Increasing `setMaximumNearestNeighbors` will avoid that runtime warning.